GRUB: Windows Memory Diagnostic
I've been trying to add the "Windows Memory Diagnostic" utility to my GRUB bootloader. I have not had any luck, though. Every script I've tried writing has resulted in an error message, with one example being a script which loads the "memtest.efi" file directly. However, when I load the "bootmgfw.efi" file, everything works fine, even with custom parameters (such as "RecoveryBCD" for the Windows Recovery Environment).
Is adding the "Windows Memory Diagnostic" utility to GRUB not possible, or is there something I'm doing wrong here? All help is greatly appreciated.

https://www.yosoygames.com.ar/wp/2020/03/installing-memtest86-on-uefi-grub2-ubuntu/
